# Error in connection with Websphere Mq through Spring

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, ibm-mq

I am using spring and JNDI to do connection with Websphere MQ. Errors are:

```
org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract javax.jms.Connection javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection() throws javax.jms.JMSException] on target [Reference Class Name: javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
```

and

```
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...
]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
```

while setting up the connection with Websphere mq.

Code I am using:

In AppMain class:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-context.xml");
JmsMessageSender jmsMessageSender = (JmsMessageSender)ctx.getBean("jmsMessageSender");
jmsMessageSender.send();
((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext)ctx).close();
```

JmsMessageSender class:

```
@Service
public class JmsMessageSender {

  @Autowired JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

  public void send() { 
      jmsTemplate.send(new MessageCreator() {
          @Override
          public Message createMessage(Session session) throws JMSException {
              Message message = session.createTextMessage("Hello");
              return message;
          }
      });
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.springframework.samples</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jms-wmq-send</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>    
    <!-- Spring version -->
    <spring-framework.version>4.0.3.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>    
  </properties>

  <dependencies>    
    <!-- Spring aritifacts -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
       <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
             <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
             <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
             <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
             <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Websphere Mq Artifacts -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.07</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.07</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.07</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
            <artifactId>dhbcore</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.07</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${basedir}/lib/dhbcore.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency> 


        <!-- javax artifacts -->
        <dependency> 
          <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId> 
          <artifactId>geronimo-jms_1.1_spec</artifactId> 
          <version>1.1.1</version> 
          <scope>provided</scope> 
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
            <artifactId>connector-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
        </dependency> -->
  </dependencies> 

  <!-- Using JDK 1.7 for compiling -->
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins> 
  </build>
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
</project>
```

spring-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

  <context:component-scan base-package="com.java.geek" />

    <bean id="connectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
       <property name="jndiName" value="jms/QueueManagerNAme"/>
       <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
       <property name="cache" value="true" />
       <property name="proxyInterface"  value="javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jndiTemplate" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate">
        <property name="environment">
        <props>
        <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory</prop>
        <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">iiop://localhost:2809</prop>
        </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"> 
        <property name="connectionFactory"><ref bean="connectionFactory" />  </property> 
        <property name="pubSubDomain"><value>false</value></property>
        <property name="defaultDestination"><ref bean="destination" /></property>
   </bean>  

    <bean id="destination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiTemplate">
        <ref bean="jndiTemplate"/>
        </property>
        <property name="jndiName">
        <value>jms/Queuename</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <bean id="jmsMessageSender" class="com.java.geek.JmsMessageSender"> 
        <property name="jmsTemplate"><ref bean="jmsTemplate"/></property>     
    </bean> 

    </beans>
```

Errors:

```
Starting connection with Websphere mq
Aug 03, 2016 12:08:28 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@3ee02299: startup date [Wed Aug 03 12:08:28 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Aug 03, 2016 12:08:28 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-context.xml]
Aug 03, 2016 12:08:29 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory registerBeanDefinition
INFO: Overriding bean definition for bean 'jmsMessageSender': replacing [Generic bean: class [com.java.geek.JmsMessageSender]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\XYZ\IBM\rationalsdp\workspace\Myworkspace\spring-jms-wmq-send\target\classes\com\java\geek\JmsMessageSender.class]] with [Generic bean: class [com.java.geek.JmsMessageSender]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [spring-context.xml]]

Aug 03, 2016 12:08:31 PM com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers
WARNING: NMSV0609W: A Reference object looked up from the context "SomeCell/nodes/SomeNode/servers/server1" with the name "jms/QueueManagerName" was sent to the JNDI Naming Manager and was returned unprocessed. Reference data follows:
Reference Factory Class Name: com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSConnectionFactoryFactory
Reference Factory Class Location URLs: <null>
Reference Class Name: javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
Address Type: JCARA
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...
Address Type: ADDR_TYPE_WAS7_WMQRA_CLIENT_CF
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 11 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69 6c 2e 48 61 73 68 4d 61 70 5 7 ffffffda ffffffc1 ffffffc3 16 60  ...
Address Type: JCA
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...
Type: ADDR_TYPE_PROVIDER_HREF
Content: cells/SomeCell/nodes/SomeNode/servers/server1/resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider
Address Type: JMS
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...


Exception in thread "P=309826:O=0:CT" org.springframework.aop.AopInvocationException: AOP configuration seems to be invalid: tried calling method [public abstract javax.jms.Connection javax.jms.ConnectionFactory.createConnection() throws javax.jms.JMSException] on target [Reference Class Name: javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory
Address Type: JCARA
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...
Address Type: ADDR_TYPE_WAS7_WMQRA_CLIENT_CF
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 11 6a 61 76 61 2e 75 74 69 6c 2e 48 61 73 68 4d 61 70 5 7 ffffffda ffffffc1 ffffffc3 16 60  ...
Address Type: JCA
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...
Type: ADDR_TYPE_PROVIDER_HREF
Content: cells/SomeCell/nodes/SomeNode/servers/server1/resources.xml#builtin_mqprovider
Address Type: JMS
AddressContents: ffffffac ffffffed 0 5 73 72 0 16 6a 61 76 61 78 2e 6e 61 6d 69 6e 67 2e 52 65 66 65 72 65 6e 63 65 ffffffe8 ffffffc6  ...
]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:325)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:481)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:566)
    at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:557)
    at com.java.geek.JmsMessageSender.send(JmsMessageSender.java:29)
    at com.java.geek.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:25)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:619)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: Haven't seen that error before but looks to be something relating to spring, rather than JMS or MQ

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am also tracking from where it is coming! :)

Comment: Are you trying to connect to an MQ queue? If so where is your queue object defined in your JNDI definitions?